# Upgrade Jenkins on Ubuntu and SSL cert goes insecure and Windows nodes will not connect

Tags: ssl, jenkins, upgrade

When trying to upgrade Jenkins on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS using apt-get, the SSL certificate for the server goes insecure and our Windows nodes, connecting over port 8443 fail to connect.  Reverting back to snapshot "fixes" the issue but Jenkins is still not upgraded.  Any help would be appreciated.

Took a snapshot in vCenter, ssh into Ubuntu and stop the Jenkins service.  Run apt-get to upgrade Jenkins ONLY and restart the Ubuntu instance.  Then, failure.  Reverting to snapshot brings the environment back to stable with secure SSL certificate.